# Show that there is an odd biholomorphic function $g$ on the unit disk such that $g(z)^2=f(z^2).$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be biholomorphic (i.e. holomorphic and injective) on the unit disk with $f(0)=0$. Show that there is a biholomorphic $g$ on the unit disk such that $g(z)^2=f(z^2)$. Show that this function satisfies also $g(-z)=-g(z)$.

---

My attempt:

Consider the power series expansion 
$$f(z)=f'(0)z+\cdots$$
so
$$f(z^2)=f'(0)z^2+\cdots=z^2(f'(0)+\cdots)$$
Therefore, we have 
$$ g(z)=z\cdot(f'(0)+\cdots)^{1/2}$$
defined on a neighborhood of $0$.

But how to extend the function to the whole unit disk? (Schwarz reflection principal?) And how to make the function to be an odd function?

There seems to be a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562701/if-f-is-analytic-and-injective-on-the-unit-disc-and-bf0-f0-subseteq), but one important condition in that question does not hold here. So both ways do not work.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468336/prove-the-existence-of-an-analytic-function

Comment: Something can be "principal", but you are thinking about "principle".

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Haha, nice word game.

Comment: $\frac{f(z^2)}{z^2}$ doesn't vanish since $f$ is bijective. Thus $z (\frac{f(z^2)}{z^2})^{1/2}$ is holomorphic and oddness is obvious.